# how to retrieve and view biginteger from bigquery using R (bigrquery package)?

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I have a column of data (minute_ids) in BigQuery and I am using the great "bigrquery" package to work with the data.

The field is an integer of >12 digits and so displays as 10 digit max 32bit char in R, ie.201501190000 displays in R as 2147483647.

how do I display the full integer in R, and is this done before or assigned to the query function.

Answer (score 1):

STRING(minute_id) as minutes

then convert back
minuteconvert <- as.integer64(res$minutes)
minuteconvert <- as.data.frame(minuteconvert)